# Can I turn off gedit antialiasing?

Tags: fonts, gedit

As the text seems blurry I'd like to disable antialiasing in `gedit`.

I don't see anything related in the program's `Preferences`.

The problem appeared after upgrade from 12.04 to 14.04:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution, do:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

then open tweak tool, go to Fonts and there you can select what kind of antialiasing you want to use.

PS. This will change antialiasing for the entire system, not just gedit.

Comment: Thanks, but the only blurry text is in `gedit` - while the background is `white` (`Ubuntu` / `Ubuntu Mono` font). This seems as gedit is treated differently.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: There it is: http://img842.imageshack.us/img842/7538/rjsw.png . Notice that line indexes are not blurry, but the colored text is.

Comment: Try setting antialigning to grayscale, and go to gedit Preference and set it to use system fonts, I don't think it will fix it, but it will make the fonts look better. Also, compleatlly unrelated, try Aptana Studio for web programming

Comment: System font is `Ubuntu Mono 13`, mine is 11. Bigger blurry text is not exactly what I need :) . `Greyscale` `antialiasing` looks different - better in gedit, but worse everywhere else, mainly web browser.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [known](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+3.0/+bug/1309785) and [fixed bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+3.0/+bug/1309785/comments/7) `in GNOME GTK 3.10` [used in Ubuntu Trusty 14.04].

It has been fixed in GTK+ 3.13.7 (unstable release).
The fix will be available for the GTK+ 3.14 stable version in September, per Sébastien Wilmet (https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=715008#c27).

The solution is to patch the gedit desktop launcher (file `gedit.desktop`), setting an env parameter. The command line to use in a Terminal (`Ctrl+Alt+T`) is :

```
$ sudo sed -i "s|Exec=gedit %U|# Exec=gedit %U\nExec=env GTK_DEBUG=no-pixel-cache gedit %U|g" /usr/share/applications/gedit.desktop
```

This will comment out the original `Exec=gedit %U` and add the new `Exec=` cmd. line with the env setting.

Comment: `It has been fixed in GTK+ 3.13.7` ... does this help? We don't even have 3.12 in Trusty. This is too much frustrating :(